# kApplicationWillBecomeActive unpause the game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In one of my SKScenes I'm listening to the NSNotification kApplicationWillBecomeActive. 
Every time the app becomes active it sets the pause status of the scene to false! any ideas?

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationAppBecameActive:) name:kNotificationAppBecameActive object:nil];
```

I'm looking for a solution that will help me distinguish between the cases.

Thanks

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Comment accepted - I've added code.
Can you pls take down the down vote? 
First day in StackOverflow :)

Comment: You also need to add the code for `notificationAppBecameActive:`.

Comment: Actually no code is even needed,  the issue is an apple bug, not his code

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes, code is needed. How can we know this is a bug in Apple's frameworks if the OP doesn't show what code they've written?

Comment: @rmadddy It has nothing to do with the problem thought.. I override the function at the same class and it only logs something.

Comment: @rmaddy no he doesn't

Comment: Only because in this case it is a known bug, if this was a case where more info is needed, then I would agree that code would be posted.  Sometimes  having too much in an answer can be a problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to override setPause and set it according to your needs

```
  -(void) setPaused:(BOOL)paused
 {
    [super setPaused:self.isGamePaused];
 }
```

Comment: This answer will only work if you want 100% manual control of how the scene gets paused and unpaused.  If you use animations or other automated features that changes the pause behind the scenes,  you will end up having to keep track of when these things happen and change the `self.isGamePaused` variable accordingly.

Comment: I do  want 100% manual control of how the scene gets paused and unpaused.

Comment: In your particular circumstance it may work, but if somebody else with this problem sees it, it may not work for them, that is why I added the comment.